# Pandas efficiently cut column with bins argument based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"category": ["A", "B"]*5, "value": np.random.uniform(size=10)})

print(test_df)
#  category     value
#0        A  0.548814
#1        B  0.715189
#2        A  0.602763
#3        B  0.544883
#4        A  0.423655
#5        B  0.645894
#6        A  0.437587
#7        B  0.891773
#8        A  0.963663
#9        B  0.383442
```

I want to bin the `value` column using [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), but the `bins` parameter needs to vary based on the `category` column.

Specifically, I want to use the following dictionary to define what bins to use for `cut`:

```
bins = {
    "A": [0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1],
    #     0,    1,    2,    3,    4   <-- corresponding bin value
    "B": [0.00, 0.33, 0.66, 1]
    #     0,    1,    2,    3         <-- corresponding bin value
}
```

I came up with the following solution, which is to first cut the `value` columns using all the bins:

```
cuts = {
    c: pd.cut(test_df["value"], bins=bins[c], labels=range(1, len(bins[c]))) for c in bins
}
```

Then using [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to assign the appropriate bin back to `test_df`:

```
test_df["bin"] = np.select(*zip(*[(test_df["category"] == c, cuts[c]) for c in bins]))
print(test_df)
#  category     value  bin
#0        A  0.548814    3
#1        B  0.715189    3
#2        A  0.602763    3
#3        B  0.544883    2
#4        A  0.423655    2
#5        B  0.645894    2
#6        A  0.437587    2
#7        B  0.891773    3
#8        A  0.963663    4
#9        B  0.383442    2
```

This is the correct answer, but is there a more efficient way? Ideally there should be a way that doesn't involve calling `cut` on each of the different bins. In my real-world data I have much more than 2 bins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use numpy with np.searchsorted:

```
test_df['bin'] = [np.searchsorted(bins[i], v) for i, v in test_df.values]
```

Output:

```
  category     value  bin
0        A  0.548814    3
1        B  0.715189    3
2        A  0.602763    3
3        B  0.544883    2
4        A  0.423655    2
5        B  0.645894    2
6        A  0.437587    2
7        B  0.891773    3
8        A  0.963663    4
9        B  0.383442    2
```

***Timings***

> %timeit np.select(*zip(*[(test_df["category"] == c, cuts[c]) for c in
>   bins]))
>   1.21 ms ± 14.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

and

> %timeit [np.searchsorted(bins[i], v) for i, v in test_df.values]
>   301 µs ± 4.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: Interesting, but this works in my case because I'm using labels based on `range` correct?

Comment: I think we use that index returned by np.searchsorted to get the label you want. If I understand your question correctly.

Comment: timing for my method is actually worse because you're not including the creation of `cuts`

Answer (score 0):

Another one to go about the problem is using  `groupby`

```py
def applied(x):
    _bins = bins[x.category.iat[0]]
    return pd.cut(x.value, bins=_bins, labels=range(1,len(_bins)))

test_df['bin']= test_df.groupby('category').apply(applied).reset_index(level= 0, drop= True)
```

but it's actually quite slow compared to @Scott Boston's